# Two contardicting aws policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, credentials, aws-policies

I've got a theoretic question regarding AWS IAM policies.
What happens when two polices contradict each other?
 
One ALLOW using a resource, and another DENY the resource?
Thanks,
      Omer

Comment: Deny takes precedence https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

Comment: See [Policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html): generally explicit deny > explicit allow > implicit deny.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) by AWS, this is called an explicit deny. If the enforcement code finds even one explicit deny that applies, the code returns a final decision of **Deny**.